# How to write Python if else in single line?

Tags: python

```
category.is_parent = True if self.request.get('parentKey') is not None else category.is_parent = False
```

Above is the code in which I am trying to write a if else in a single line and it is giving me this syntax error

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression"
```

But if I write it in following way it works fine

```
if self.request.get('parentKey') is not None:
     category.is_parent = True
else:
    category.is_parent = False
```

Comment: You don't need an id/else here. Just do `category.is_parent = self.request.get('parentKey') != None`

Comment: If you put it on one line, it's a slightly different syntax. `x = a if condition else b`, and you can chain multiple ones up too, like `x = a if condition else b if condition2 else c`

Comment: The structure you tried is '`<assignment>` if condition else `<assignment>`'; the structure that's allowed is '`variable` = `<expression>`' where `expression` is of the form '`<value1> if <condition> else <value2>`'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
category.is_parent = True if self.request.get('parentKey') else False
```

To check only against `None`:

```
category.is_parent = True if self.request.get('parentKey') is not None else False
```

Comment: This isn't exactly the same with what the OP wants. Doesn't handle the case where `self.request.get('parentKey')` is *falsy* and not `None`

Comment: @SaimAbdullahCh You can accept it as the answer of your question :)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye How do you know that?

Comment: Because `''`, `0`, `[]` etc. will all return `False`, but it should be `True` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

`category.is_parent = True if self.request.get('parentKey') is not None else False`

Or even simpler in this case:

`category.is_parent = self.request.get('parentKey') is not None`

Answer (score 0):

You can write this with a one liner but using the [][] python conditional syntax. Like so:

```
category.is_parent = [False,True][self.request.get('parentKey') is not None
```

The first element in the first array is the result for the else part of the condition and the second element is the result when the condition in the second array evaluates to True.